# How to manage multiple Bluetooth mics on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

My car has Bluetooth integration, yet even when parked with the radio turned off, so long as the engine is running, the car's mic takes precedence over the very nice Bluetooth dictation mic I'd prefer to use. How can I force my iPhone to choose the dictation mic when parked without unpairing from the car?

Comment: this is more of a car question then apple products.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Not really. RI Swamp Yankee is trying to set order of precedence on his iPhone for Bluetooth devices. What devices are being connected (car, mic, speakers, etc.) is really irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

There is an order of precedence for Bluetooth devices connected to iPhone. See [iPhone Bluetooth Pairing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19843915/2654989) on StackOverflow:

> > What determines precedence is the order they are connected for that session. The last connected device has the highest precedence and is the one used.

Therefore, to ensure the dictation mic is used, connect it after your car connects. If it's already connected when the car connects, you would need to disconnect the dictation mic and reconnect it. (Turning it off and then on again should accomplish this, but without knowing what device it is, it is impossible for me to state this with any certainty.)